# Code to hide winform when application loses focus

Tags: vb.net

I have been trying to build a procedure that will hide my winform when the application loses focus. I was able to come up with some code, but is not working properly. Here is my code:

```
    Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    Me.LostFocus += New EventHandler(AddressOf Form1_LostFocus)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
End Sub
```

The error I am getting on line:

```
 Me.LostFocus += New EventHandler(AddressOf Form1_LostFocus)
```

It says that Public Event is an event and cannot be called directly. Use RaiseEvent statement to raise an event.

I am not sure how to use RaiseEvent so i am looking for some help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using C# syntax for your manual wiring.

For VB.Net, it should look like this:

```
AddHandler Me.LostFocus, AddressOf Form1_LostFocus
```

Or just add the Handles syntax to the method (as aphoria demonstrated):

```
Private Sub Form1_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
                            Handles Me.LostFocus
  Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you need to add an event handler programmatically. Just put your code in the `LostFocus` event sub.

Just do this:

```
  Private Sub Form1_LostFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.LostFocus
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
  End Sub
```